# Empty page after h:commandButton submit

Tags: jsf

I have an JSF 2.2 page which contain forms and a `<h:commandButton>` to call the method, after the submit button, the method called successfully and all instructions works fine

**Problem**: 
After the button submit, I got an empty page and the URL in the browser is still unchanged

What I want is that after the submit, the page stays the same and shows a growl message.

managedBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="consignmentShipBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ConsignmentShipBean implements Serializable{
    public void send(){
        //some instructions to do
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful",  "__") );
    }
}
```

page.xhtml

```
<p:growl id="growl"  globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{consignmentShipBean.send}"  />
</h:form>
```

**UPDATE**
the result after the button submit:

[image]

Comment: @BalusC my firefox is infected, I tried to test my page in chrome there is nothing strange in the console browser, I got only a blank page

Comment: @BalusC you can see my edit

Comment: The problem is not visible in the information provided so far. Imagine us having a completely blank project with everything set to bare defaults and most recent versions. How could we reproduce your problem based on only the information provided so far in the question? When I copypaste your bean and XHTML and stub/autocomplete the missing code (Java imports, HTML head/body) as per the standards, everything works just fine for me. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score -1):

You have to perform an Ajax request, not an usual request. Use a standard button or a PrimeFaces one for it:

```
<h:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{consignmentShipBean.send}" >
    <f:ajax update="growl"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Or

```
<p:commandButton value="Send" 
    actionListener="#{consignmentShipBean.send}" update="growl" />
```

Comment: Did you reproduce OP's problem based on the information provided so far? Even without ajax, page should stay the same (only refreshed) and message should show up. The page should not blank out at all. This answer does not explain anywhere why OP faced that problem.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was a transitional blank page and then the original URL again. @BalusC, Should I delete this answer? Thanks.